# Oracle Create Materialized View Syntax

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I've got a materialized view that I've been asked to look at that will not compile. This is part of a database inherited from another company via acquisition. I suspect this is referencing another database that we didn't receive but I can't understand or find the syntax for the USING () portion of this. I've changed some of the names around, but the syntax should be the same. Could someone explain to me what the heck this thing is doing? We've got some Crystal reports that are trying to hit the same table, but can't find it since it doesn't exist in the database being used...

> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "SCHEMA"."MV_NAME" ("COLUMN1") 
>   USING ("MV_NAME", (10, 'DNS_NAME', 1, 0, 0, "ANOTHER_SCHEMA", "TIME_DIMENSION", '2015-04-08 09:32:17', 0, 30278, '2015-04-08 09:32:17', '', 0, 8420605171713, 0, NULL)
>   , 2097472, 8, ('2014-12-17 08:14:17', 543, 0, 0, 8421320914252, 268435456, 0, 0, 2, NULL, NULL)) 
>   REFRESH FORCE AS SELECT

Comment: There's no such syntax in Oracle; in `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW` the keyword `USING` is optional and only has to do with using (or not using) one or more indexes on the MV - and it wouldn't appear in that position in the MV definition anyway. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6002.htm#i2145767

Comment: [Looks like this came from data pump](http://www.strategicdbs.com/p/problems-creating-mview-ddl-using-data.html). Are you able to get the MV's DDL from the original database, in a more useable format?

Comment: If not, and you have the actual view query (not shown in your question, but presuambly that exists in your real code), you may be able to to just scrap the `using` part and recreate a perhaps-not-identical MV? Out of interest, what error do you get running this as-is?

Comment: Well its reassuring to hear that this syntax is showing up because it's from a data dump. I think that makes sense since the dba pulled it from sort of backup he did from a while back. I went and pulled the SQL for creating the view out of the database, when I try running it I get the error that a table or view doesn't exist. I'm trying to figure out if we did not receive a schema when the database was provided during acquisition or if there was a database link or something for access to the other schema. Any way to confirm either idea?

Comment: You can see if ANOTHER_SCHEMA exists in `ALL_USERS`; assuming that schema name also appears in the SQL you pulled manually. If it's using a database link you'll see an `@` in that SQL of course, unless there's a synonym hiding that. You might also have unqualified table references in the query that are actually synonyms (or views). Doesn't the error line number tell you what it can't find?

Comment: ANOTHER_SCHEMA doesn't exist in all_users, when I pulled just the select statement out and tried running it the error indicating the table wasn't found gave the line number for the table in ANOTHER_SCHEMA. I'm thinking we didn't get everything that we should have in this database.. crud!  Thank you for the insights and help!